# WCF Configuration Error - Extension name not registered

Tags: wcf, web-services, rest

I am self hosting a REST service that uses a custom BehaviorExtension.  When I add the behavior extension to the ServiceBehaviors I get the following error:

> "Invalid element in configuration.  The extension name 'unityServiceBehavior' is not registered in the collection at system.serviceModel/extensions/behaviorExtensions."

My App.Config is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

    <system.serviceModel>

        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors"     name="My.Core.Services.PartyService">
                <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="RESTBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding"    name="PartyService" contract="My.Core.Services.IPartyService" />
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding"  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
                <host>
                   <baseAddresses>
                       <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/parties" />
                   </baseAddresses>
                </host>
             </service>
        </services>

        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="MyServiceTypeBehaviors" >
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />

                    <!--Adding this behavior causes the error />-->
                    <UnityServiceBehavior />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>

           <endpointBehaviors>
               <behavior name="RESTBehavior">
                  <webHttp helpEnabled="true" />
               </behavior>
           </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>

        <extensions>
           <behaviorExtensions>
               <add name="UnityServiceBehavior" type="My.Core.Services.UnityServiceBehavior,     My.Core.Services, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
           </behaviorExtensions>
        </extensions>  

    </system.serviceModel>


    <startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup>    </configuration>
```

Any Ideas on this?

Edit: I read somewhere that the Behavior extension needs to be registered with configuration in order for it to be loaded.

Is there something special that I need to do to register an extension with the configuration?

Thanks.

Comment: a casing issue maybe ? <add name="unityServiceBehavior"  (notice lowercase u)

Comment: I see the lowercase u.  Still getting the error.  Good eyes rene!  I will edit my post with this correction.

Answer (score 1):

To add on the already excellent answers above: I encountered this error after adding this to the machine.config files.

I only noticed later, while troubleshooting that the .NET version of my application pool was not the same as the .NET version where I adapted the machine.config files. (v2.0 vs v4.0).

Setting the application pool to the correct version fixed this error for me.

Quite obvious, but easy to miss for the unexperienced ones with IIS (like me sometimes).

Answer (score 0):

UnityServiceBehavior class needs to derive from BehaviorExtensionElement.

Can I suggest too that you change your name of your behavior as follows:

```
    <serviceBehaviors>   
            <behavior name="MyServiceTypeBehaviors" >   
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />   

                <!--Adding this behavior causes the error />-->   
                <unityServiceBehavior />   
            </behavior>   
        </serviceBehaviors> 


       <behaviorExtensions> 
           <add name="unityServiceBehavior" type="My.Core.Services.UnityServiceBehavior,     My.Core.Services, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" /> 
       </behaviorExtensions>
```

as you've given the element the same name as the class (even case wise) it may also cloud the issue...

In the class where you derive from BehaviorExtensionElement you need to override CreateBehavior()

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your input.  Yes, I have already created a class that inherits from the BehaviorExtensionElement.  Also, I agree on the naming.  It was just a typo on my post.  Anyway, I got past the error message stated above by registering the the the behavior in the GAC.  Now i'm getting a new but similar error.  I suspect it has something to do with my 64 bit machine.

Answer (score 0):

Originally I was getting the following error:

> "Invalid element in configuration. The extension name 'unityServiceBehavior' is not registered in the collection at system.serviceModel/extensions/behaviorExtensions."

I got past this error by striping out the behavior into it's on dll (Now called My.UnityWCF) and registering the custom behavior in the GAC.  However, now i'm getting a new but similar error.

> The extension of type 'My.UnityWCF.UnityServiceBehavior, My.UnityWCF, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ab794c43d4083d4c' is not registered in the extension collection 'behaviorExtensions'.

I used the WCF Configuration Editor to add the behavior to the behaviorExtensions collection.

```
<behaviorExtensions>
    <add name="unityWCF" type="My.UnityWCF.UnityServiceBehavior, My.unityWCF, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" /> 
</behaviorExtensions>
```